# Can std::array be used in a constexpr class?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constexpr

I am currently creating a class with a `constexpr` constructor and I wonder if I can use an `std::array` to store the data of this class. Does the standard explicitly specify that an `std::array` has a `constexpr` constructor and that its contents can be accessed at compile-time ?

Comment: `std::array` does not have a `constexpr` constructor to the best of my knowledge

Comment: `std::array` has no (user-defined) constructor. It's an aggregate.

Comment: Note that although you can store the data, you'll have a harder time extracting it in a constexpr way.

Comment: There are several library defect reports out that add `constexpr` to various functions. So you cannot get your data in a `constexpr` manner in C++11 but this should be resolved in the next language version (and possibly sooner depending on your library implementor) to mark most of them (all?) as `constexpr`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Because `std::array<T, N>` is an aggregate, it can be initialized as a `constexpr` if and only if the underlying type `T` has a `constexpr` constructor (when presented with each initializer you provide).

Answer (score 12):

Based on the comment by @MarkGlisse: this [compiles](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2yUyxm$13)

```
#include <array> 
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, std::size_t N> 
struct X 
{ 
   constexpr X(const std::array<T,N>& a):arr(a){} 

   private: 
   std::array<T,N> arr; 
}; 

constexpr std::array<int,2> a {{ 13, 18 }}; 
constexpr X<int,2> x = a;

int main() 
{        
}
```

I believe I have found the relevant quote from the Standard here:

**12.1 Constructors [class.ctor]**

> 6 A default constructor that is defaulted and not deﬁned as deleted is
>   implicitly deﬁned when it is odrused (3.2) to create an object of its
>   class type (1.8) or when it is explicitly defaulted after its ﬁrst
>   declaration. The implicitly-deﬁned default constructor performs the
>   set of initializations of the class that would be performed by a
>   user-written default constructor for that class with no
>   ctor-initializer (12.6.2) and an empty compound-statement. If that
>   user-written default constructor would be ill-formed, the program is
>   ill-formed. If that user-written default constructor would satisfy the
>   requirements of a constexpr constructor (7.1.5), the implicitly-deﬁned
>   default constructor is constexpr.

This looks essentially like @BenVoigt's answer.

Comment: `#include <cstdlib>
    #include <array>
    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    struct X {
      constexpr X(std::array<T,N>& a):arr(a){}
     private:
      std::array<T,N> arr;
    };
    
    std::array<int,2> a = { 13, 18 };
    X<int,2> x = a;` compiles for me...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Try adding `constexpr` in front of `a` and `X`, and it won't compile!

Comment: `#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct X
{
  constexpr X(const std::array<T,N>& a):arr(a){}
  private:
  std::array<T,N> arr;
};
constexpr std::array<int,2> a = { 13, 18 };
constexpr X<int,2> x = a;`
compiles just fine.

Comment: @MarcGlisse OK, tnx, so any clue why it compiles? ;-)

Comment: chris said it, std::array is an aggregate. What part exactly confuses you?