# Data structure with get, returning a constexpr (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, tuples, c++14, constexpr

I am currently looking for a data-structure that encapsulates data for compile-time access. Thereby, the accessed values should returned as constexpr.

While a tuple does have a constexpr constructor, the `get` function of the tuple does not return a constexpr.

*Does such a data structure exist or is it possible to manually define such a data structure?*

The final goal is to pack compile time known values within some kind of object, pass it (via template) to a function, access the elements there and have the compile time known values directly pasted inplace in the binary as constants. For my purpose the encapsulation part is crucial.

Comment: Perhaps [`std::array` if you do it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267399/can-stdarray-be-used-in-a-constexpr-class)

Comment: https://github.com/Arcoth/Constainer

Comment: `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: Using `std:array` in the example above, the access to the array in the struct is compiled to `callq std::array<int, 2ul>::operator[](unsigned long) const` which is not the constant at all, but a memory access I assume...

Comment: To be clear: It may be constant, but it is not the integer constant that is stored within the array, as I want it to be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of C++14, `std::tuple` does accept a `constexpr std::get`

```
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
   constexpr std::tuple<int, int, int> t { 1, 2, 3 };
   static_assert(std::get<0>(t) == 1, "");
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cafb11c5e7508cc)

Similarly, you can use `std::array` as well with `std::get` (and also the `operator[]` is now `constexpr`). Raw C-arrays can also be done.

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
   constexpr std::array<int, 3> a {{ 1, 2, 3 }};
   static_assert(std::get<0>(a) == 1, "");
   static_assert(a[0] == 1, "");
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87dd8d9b273b091a)