# Cannot make std::array a constexpr in C++

Tags: c++

I am getting 'error C3615: constexpr function 'to_array' cannot result in a constant expression' compiler error with VS2017 in the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
static constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, sizeof(T)> to_array(T value)
{
    std::array<std::uint8_t, sizeof(T)> result {};

    for (std::size_t i{ sizeof(T) }; i != 0 ; --i)
    {
        result[i - 1] = static_cast<uint8_t>(value >> ((sizeof(T) - i) * 8));
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr uint64_t sample = UINT64_C(0xab28ecb46814fe75);

    //error C3615: constexpr function 'to_array' cannot result in a constant expression
    constexpr auto a = to_array(sample);

    return 0;
}
```

If theoretically [std::array can be constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267399/can-stdarray-be-used-in-a-constexpr-class), why am I getting the error here?

EDIT1:

it compiles without the loop:

```
template <typename T>
static constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, sizeof(T)> to_array(T value)
{
    std::array<std::uint8_t, sizeof(T)> result {};

    //this is OK
    return result;
}
```

EDIT2:

the full error message with the loop is:

```
error C3615: constexpr function 'to_array' cannot result in a constant expression
note: failure was caused by an uninitialized variable declaration
note: see usage of 'result'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full error message is:

```
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
note: failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not declared 'constexpr'
note: see usage of 'std::array<uint8_t,8>::operator []'
note: while evaluating 'to_array(12333367839138578037)'
fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

If we now take a look at the declaration of `operator[]` we see that it is not `constexpr` yet in that versions of Microsoft STD implementation:

```
reference operator[](_In_range_(0, _Size - 1) size_type _Pos)
```

The workaround is to use a C-array and then convert it into `std::array`:

```
template<std::size_t... is, std::size_t n = sizeof...(is)>
constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, n>
    to_array(std::uint8_t (&arr)[n], std::index_sequence<is...>)
{
    return {arr[is]...};
}

template <typename T>
constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, sizeof(T)> to_array(T value)
{
    std::uint8_t result[sizeof(T)];
    ...
    return to_array(result, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof(T)>{});
}
```

or

```
template<typename T, std::size_t... is>
constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, sizeof(T)> 
    to_array(T value, std::index_sequence<is...>)
{
    return {static_cast<std::uint8_t>(value >> ((sizeof(T) - is - 1) * 8))...};
}

template <typename T>
constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, sizeof(T)> to_array(T value)
{
    return to_array(value, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof(T)>{});
}
```

But you can't use `operator[]` on the result in `constexpr` context anyway.

Answer (score 5):

> If theoretically [std::array can be constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267399/can-stdarray-be-used-in-a-constexpr-class), why am I getting the error here?

The link you are providing is dealing with *constructing* an `std::array` as part of a `constexpr`, not doing anything else with it, like you do.

> it compiles without the loop

Your error does't have anything to do with the loop itself, as it does directly with using `operator[]` of `std::array` inside a `constexpr` function body.

`operator[]` of `std::array` [is `constexpr` since C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at), but [it seem MSVC 19 hasn't implemented it](https://godbolt.org/z/KlsKH5) even though it's in the spec. So in your case, building with C++17 enabled (compiler flag `/std:c++latest`) won't directly solve the issue :-(

The good news is that [MSVC 20 is conforming just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/TN0nCW) :-)

Comment: I think OP's code makes MSVC unhappy even with `/std:c++17`.

Comment: I am compiling with ISO C++ Latest Draft Standard (/std:c++latest) in MSVC 2017

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky, then please cite the full error message emitted by the compiler.

Comment: compiles just fine with VS2017 15.8.2 and /std:c++17

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today. I decided to try and wrap std::array to see if I could add constexpr support. I had just begun and this happened to work before I had overloaded the [] operator.

```
template <typename T, unsigned S> struct _array : public std::array<T,S> {};
```

Using _array in place of std::array now works.